# How to sum all G-values?

Tags: r, sum

After using the G.test on all rows of my data subset

```
apply(datamixG +1 , 1, G.test)
```

I get an output for each row that looks like this

```
[[1]]

        G-test for given probabilities

data:  [(newX,,i)
G = 3.9624, df = 1, p-value = 0.04653
```

I have 46 rows. I need to sum the df and G-values. Is there a way to have R report the G-values differently and/or sum all of the G-values and df?

Comment: Can you give more details about `G.test` you are using (from which package is it)?

Comment: You could improve your questions by 1) Including all packages you're using; 2) Building reproducible examples by including a sample dataset; 3) Listening to the SO users who've been asking these same things on every single one of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you're using the `G.test` function from the `RVAideMemoire` package:

```
# Sample data (always a good idea to post!)
dat <- matrix(1:4, nrow=2)
library(RVAideMemoire)
tests <- apply(dat, 1, G.test)
```

You can use `unlist` and `lapply` to extract a single value from each element in a list and to return a vector of the results:

```
dfs <- unlist(lapply(tests, "[[", "parameter"))
dfs
# df df 
#  1  1 
sum(dfs)
# [1] 2

Gs <- unlist(lapply(tests, "[[", "statistic"))
Gs
#         G         G 
# 1.0464963 0.6795961
sum(Gs)
# [1] 1.726092
```